# Unit Testing / Performance Testing approaches for SharePoint Projects

Tags: testing, unit-testing

Its sort of an open ended question but can anybody share the experiences, approaches, tools and infrastructure to implement following in their SharePoint Projects:

1. Unit Testing
2. Performance Testing
3. Load Testing
4. Integration Testing

It will be great if people can share any pitfalls they had in their past projects. How a SharePoint Project was different then a normal .NET project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unit Testing on SharePoint only really begins to work properly when you mock the SharePoint object model using one of a few methods.

Andrew Woodward over at 21apps.com has documented his findings of this, particularly with using TypeMock Isolator for SharePoint.
http://www.21apps.com/category/agile/testing/

I also seen a recent presentation of his which demonstrated UI Testing Features available in Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate, which was quite interesting.
(Slide Deck: http://www.21apps.com/sharepoint/slides-ui-testing-bpc10/)

For Load Testing, I have seen a good presentation from Steve Smith of Combined Knowledge about using Visual Studio for Load Testing a SharePoint farm. If you contact him through Twitter I'm sure he may be able to point you to resources regarding this:
http://twitter.com/stevesmithck

Comment: Thanks James. I checked the link and there is another one by Sahil Malik http://blah.winsmarts.com/2009-6-SharePoint_and_TDD.aspx about Test Driven Development. 
It looks like that opinions are divided on how to implement normal Software Development practices.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Pex and Moles to unit test SharePoint in isolation. There are 2 tutorials to get started, available from Microsoft at:

https://www.microsoft.com/research/project/pex-and-moles-isolation-and-white-box-unit-testing-for-net/

The tutorials are:

- Unit Testing SharePoint with Moles
- Unit Testing SharePoint with Behaviors

Comment: Should point out that Pex/Moles addins are only for Visual Studio 2010 (at time of writing I couldn't see VS2008 versions).